# AWS Lambda taking 10 second to END after code returns

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

[image]

I wrote a typescript Lambda API . As the picture shows the place where `callback complete` logs, the lambda responds 10 seconds after that. You can also see that in the timestamps.

```js
export const handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  const { headers: { Authorization } } = event

  start = Date.now()

  const auth = await authorizer(Authorization)

  console.log(`Authorizer took ${Date.now() - start} seconds to complete`)

  if (!auth.isAuthenticated) {
    callback(null, { statusCode: 401, body: JSON.stringify("Unauthorized") })
    return
  }

  start = Date.now()
  const associations = await dynamoDb.query({
    // DynamoDB Query params
  }).promise()

  console.log(`DynamoDB query took ${Date.now() - start} seconds to complete`)

  const customers = associations.Items.map(association => association.customer)

  if (customers.length === 0) {
    callback(null, { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify([]) })
    return
  }

  start = Date.now()
  const customerDetails = await pool.query(`XXXXXXXX`)

  console.log(`PostgreSQL query took ${Date.now() - start} milliseconds to complete`)

  const { rows } = customerDetails

  callback(null, { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify(rows) })
  console.log('callback complete')
  return
}
```

Comment: You appear to be printing millisecond values as "XYZ took N seconds".

Comment: Also, don't mix async/await with the callback mechanism in AWS Lambda. Use one or the other, preferably async/await. Fix that problem and see if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching [AWS Documentations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html) a bit, I found this -

> When you use callbacks in your handler, the function continues to execute until the event loop is empty or the function times out. The response isn't sent to the invoker until all event loop tasks are finished.

In my case, the event loop task still had the PostgreSQL connection pooling mechanism running, hence, the lambda continued executing for 10 extra seconds.

We can still use callback, according to the documentation -

> If the function times out, an error is returned instead. You can configure the runtime to send the response immediately by setting context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop to false.

In my opinion, @jarmod 's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76291307/aws-lambda-taking-10-second-to-end-after-code-returns/76293848#comment134534474_76291307) is more clean approach here.